# Dynamic Linq query using

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use Dynamic linq query for my file filtering. Basically, I have the user define the WhereExpression and the OrderByExpression strings in an XML document which I read and then apply to a list of files to be sourced to various directions. I found a library at

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

And decided to use it but I seem to be having some issues getting started. So far, when I try to pass the where expression and the Orderby to the IQueryable list e.ge

```
 **WhereQuery**="@SubType = 02" 
 **OrderByQuery**="FormID"

      var sortedRepos = Repos.Where(dir.WhereExpression).OrderBy(dir.OrderByExpression);
```

I get the following error message.

> System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException was caught
>     Message=Operator '=' incompatible with operand types 'String' and 'Int32'
>     Source=Dynamic
>     Position=12
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.CheckAndPromoteOperands(Type signatures, String opName, Expression& left, Expression& right, Int32 errorPos)
>          at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseComparison()
>          at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalAnd()
>          at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalOr()
>          at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseExpression()
>          at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.Parse(Type resultType)
>          at System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(ParameterExpression[] parameters, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values)

Now when I do use the comparison operator like so,

```
 **WhereQuery="@SubType == 02" 
 OrderByQuery="FormID"**
```

I get the following error as well

```
System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException was caught
  Message=Operator '==' incompatible with operand types 'String' and 'Int32'
  Source=Dynamic
  Position=12
  StackTrace:
       at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.CheckAndPromoteOperands(Type signatures, String opName, Expression& left, Expression& right, Int32 errorPos)
       at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseComparison()
       at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalAnd()
       at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalOr()
       at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseExpression()
       at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.Parse(Type resultType)
       at System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(ParameterExpression[] parameters, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values)
       at System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(Type itType, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values)
       at System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.Where(IQueryable source, String predicate, Object[] values)
       at System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.Where[T](IQueryable`1 source, String predicate, Object[] values)
```

How can I correctly specify my expression so as to filter my list please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `==` instead of `=`. The former is used for comparison, the latter for assignment.

Comment: I just update my report to show what I get when I try even that. I have been on this for more than hour now,and have read the documentation over but I know I am still missing something here.

Comment: Parse your int variable to a string and compare again. Adding `.ToString()` should do it. Either that or change your SubType to an integer, seems like your design is inconsistent.

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say my design is inconsistent. The SubType property is itself a String, and I expect 02 to be treated as a String as well. Or how do I, in the WhereExpression passed in, specify that 02 is a String and not an int value please?

Comment: First of all: try omitting the blank spaces in your equation. If that doesn't work, put the `02` in a temporary variable (it's only test data, right?) and build your query as such ` **WhereQuery**="@SubType==" + temp;`

Comment: THat does not seem to work at all since, again, I simply want the user to specify a string in the XML file for the WhereExpression Value.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the `Where` method is

```
public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, 
                                     string predicate,
                                     params object[] values)
```

So you can use parameters of the desired type...

```
Where("SubType = @0", "02")
```

...or...

```
Where("SubType = @0", 2)
```

...if `SubType` is a numeric type.

`@0` just means: substitute this by the first parameter in `params`.

(the `@` before `SubType` is not necessary.)

Comment: my query is like the way you showed, but your answer did not work.Any other clue? Just to add my runtime query comparing null value to date time.

Comment: @Jha.prashant "did not work" doesn't tell me much, but maybe by revision has something to do with it?

Comment: For example : where ("{0}=@0".FormatWith(key), values[key]) and key is the property of type dateandtime which contains null as value.I removed @ but it did not work for me. Its still throwing an error.

Comment: @Jha.prashant You better put this in a question. This requires more details.

Answer (score 1):

When you have this error:

```
  Message=Operator '==' incompatible with operand types 'String' and 'Int32'
```

It means what it says.
To correct that put the value in quotation. i.e.

```
WhereQuery**="@SubType = "/"02/""
```

This should work with you..